# "In the organization of"

Tags: collocation

I was wondering if the phrase "in the organization of" might possibly be understood with the meaning "organized by". The phrase is a literal translation of the phrase we use in my mother tongue, so I was wondering how far it was from being a natural collocation in English. For example:

> The event was held **in the organization** of the company I previously worked for.

where *"in the organization"* part would be interpreted as "..was organized by the company.."

Comment: I would say "under the aegis of" or "the event was organized by."  *Organization* as a noun form of the verb "to organize" doesn't work well here.

Comment: "under the aegis of" is quite far from everyday English, even if it is technically correct. Few laypeople will understand what you mean if you phrase it that way.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Kris, I'd thought it would be an unnatural phrasing in English, just wanted to make sure. I was writing in English and only after reading later what I'd written I realized I'd used that phrase, obviously mentally translating a phrase from my own language into English.

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think so - I wouldn't read it as such, anyway. A better construction might be:

"The event was organized/held by my previous employer."

You can use either organized or held - I think it makes the sentence much more concise and readable. I also wanted to change "the company I previously worked for" as it seemed needlessly wordy, but substituted 'company' for 'employer' to avoid the confusion that it was a company you once owned.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer Rome_Leader, all clear !

Comment: **Why** would you not think so?

Comment: You just wouldn't say "in the organization of" when you mean "organized by". It's not an answer to "Who organized the party?". You would say "It was organized by X Company", not "It was held in the organization of the company."

Comment: I still don't have enough reputation to do that Rome_Leader, but as soon as I do I won't forget to upvote your answer. @Kris Are you suggesting that you don't find odd the phrase "in the organization of" meaning "organized by" in this context?